# How to Open link inside PDF page in android app using android Pdf viewer library

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I am making one PDF reader app.
I am using android pdfViewer library

```
com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2
```

My issue is their are some links inside my PDF pages. when user clicks on it the link should open in phone's default browser.

Note: I am not using Webview. PDFs are simply stored in assets folder and i am loading it from that folder

Comment: Hi, is your issue solved? I am also facing the same problem. TIA.